# NSPredicate in many to many comparison using IN operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am trying to fetch records from Core data. It is a list of tasks. `Tasks` entity has `to-many` relationship with `Tags` entity.

Now I need to fetch `tasks` with some filtered `tags`.

```
due_date = nil AND status != 2 AND (user_id = 26894 OR owner.id = 26894) AND (title contains[cd] 'shop' OR owner.name contains[cd] 'shop' OR owner.email contains[cd] 'shop' OR note contains[cd] 'shop') AND ANY tags.id IN (
    2021,
    6573,
    6588
)
```

The part

```
AND ANY tags.id IN (
        2021,
        6573,
        6588
    )
```

is causing the application to crash with following error.

```
 -[__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x163b3500
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x163b3500'
```

Here is my full method:

```
+ (NSPredicate *)predicateGetIdeasOffline {
    NSString *predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"due_date = nil AND status != 2 AND (user_id = %@ OR owner.id = %@)", [DBUsers currentUser].id, [DBUsers currentUser].id];

    if ([MKGlobals tasksSearchFilter].length > 0) {
        NSString *searchTerm = [MKGlobals tasksSearchFilter];
        predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AND (title contains[cd] '%@' OR owner.name contains[cd] '%@' OR owner.email contains[cd] '%@' OR note contains[cd] '%@')", predicateString, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm, searchTerm];
    }

    if ([MKGlobals tagsList].count > 0) {
        predicateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ AND ANY tags.id IN %@", predicateString, [MKGlobals tagsListIDs]];
    }
    return [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString];
}
```

Any help how to create such `NSPredicate`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate with nested subqueries failing to compile(core data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863505/nspredicate-with-nested-subqueries-failing-to-compilecore-data)

Comment: Are you sure [MKGlobals tagsListIDs] is returning an array?

Comment: Sure, you can see the NSLog (in question 2021, 6573, 6588)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, only because I used `NSSet` and called `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID IN %@", [set allObjects]];`. What worked for me was to completely change the NSSet to NSArray before calling the predicate function.